# How to run a command when ext4 errors are detected?

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab, ext4

I've experienced some problems in the past days. My root partition was randomly remounting `ro` (read-only) when some ext4 errors were detected.

I've got another HDD mounted at `/mnt/files` and everything under this directory is synced using Nextcloud.

When the root filesystem remounted read-only, Nextcloud started randomly deleting my data. This is not a problem as I can always restore the files from the trashbin on my server. The restore process takes a long time, so I wanted to kill Nextcloud immediately when the root filesystem remounts, to prevent further data loss.

Is it possible to run `killall nextcloud` when it remounts `ro`?

Anyway, I booted a live CD and fixed all the detected errors so it shouldn't happen again, but I want to be sure it doesn't affect my data again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this via `systemd` if you want to check every 15 minutes if your root filesystem is read-only or not:

- Create the script that checks the filesystem and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset $rootfs
unset $status
rootfs=SDXn #Replace with sda1 eg.

grep -E ''$rootfs'.*\ ro' /proc/mounts 2>&1 > /dev/null
status=$?

if [ $status = 0 ];
    then
        echo "$rootfs is not okay"
        killall nextcloud
        exit 1
    else
        echo "$rootfs is okay"
        exit 0
fi
```

- Create the `systemd service` in `/lib/systemd/system/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kill nextcloud client when filesystem is read-only

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh
```

- Create the `systemd timer` in `/lib/systemd/system/` and enable/start with `systemctl [enable|start] name_of_file.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kill nextcloud client when filesystem is read-only

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/15

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Please note that the .timer and .service files need to have the same name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it. There's still one problem: Nextcloud starts wiping data immediately after the rootfs remounts read-only. I'll probably use a while loop instead of `[Timer]`, and add a `sleep 15` command, so it checks every 15 seconds.

Comment: You can use a loop or adjust the timer accordingly. The result should be the same.